# Why doesn't die in alarm signal handler kill the process?

Tags: perl, die

From How can I specify timeout limit for Perl system call?

```
eval { 
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n" }; # NB: \n required 
    alarm $timeout; 
    $nread = sysread SOCKET, $buffer, $size; 
    alarm 0; 
}; 
if ($@) { 
    die unless $@ eq "alarm\n";   # propagate unexpected errors 
    # timed out 
} 
else { 
    # didn't 
}
```

If a timeout happens, should `sub { die "alarm\n" };`  cause the end of a process. I guess I am not able to understand `die`. This http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/PERL/node111.html says that "The die() function is used to quit your script and display a message for the user to read". However, in the case of the script above, the script will process the code in #timed out. Also sysread continues to work. Instead of sysread, I had a perl script that slept for 30 seconds. My timeout was set to 10 seconds. As expected, the code in #timed out is executed but the script continued to sleep.Any inputs appreciated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`die`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html) doesn't cause the end of a process, it throws an exception.

Now, if nothing catches an exception, that ends a process, but you have [code](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) in place to catch this very exception.

The process doesn't end because you explicitly prevent it from ending.

---

Since you're not very clear on what behaviour you are getting, there could be another possibility: That you are using a Windows build of Perl.

The `alarm` is a Unix system call. It's very purpose (sending a signal after a certain amount of time has passed) makes no sense on Windows since Windows doesn't have signals.

Perl emulates `alarm` to some extent, but only in a very limited manner. `sleep` could very well be the only operation that's interruptable by `alarm`. Otherwise, the timeout is only checked between statements.

So it won't interrupt `sysread`, but once `sysread` returns, Perl notices the timeout expired and emulate a signal then.

Comment: @doon, Added alternate answer.

Comment: Thanks. I am using UNIX version of perl. Thanks for letting me know that die is an exception. I did not realize that

Comment: @doon, In contrast, there's [`exit`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exit.html). But normally you want `die` because it allows people to handle errors if they so choose.

Comment: @doon, Also note that SIGALRM will normally kill your process, so your script would be forcibly existed if you didn't use `local $SIG{ALRM}`. Using `local $SIG{ALRM}` allows your destructors to run, though.

Answer (score 1):

From **man alarm**

```
   alarm() arranges for a SIGALRM signal to be delivered to the calling process in seconds seconds.
```

Before **sigalarm** is delivered execution reaches else block. Insert a **STDIN** before **sysread** so that **sigalarm** triggers resulting expected results.

Answer (score 1):

> "Instead of sysread, I had a perl script that slept for 30 seconds. My
>   timeout was set to 10 seconds. As expected, the code in #timed out is
>   executed but the script continued to sleep."

Really?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => qw(all);

eval {
    open my $fh, '<', $0 || die;
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub {
        print STDERR "hello!\n";
        die "bye!";
    };
    alarm 3;
    while (<$fh>) {
        print $_;
        sleep 1;
    }
    close $fh;
};

if ($@) {
    print "HERE: $@\n";
}
```

The output:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => qw(all);
hello!
HERE: bye! at ./test.pl line 9, <$fh> line 3.
```

Over in the expected 3 seconds; this is still the case if I just use "sleep 100" instead of the file read.  Note that *if you spawn a subprocess,* alarm will not kill that and the parent process must wait.  In that case, the "hello!" in the signal handler will appear when alarm fires, but the eval which catches the die will not complete until the subprocess does.

Comment: Thanks. This is useful. The code that you had written after alarm i.e. the sleep routine is the s ame that I had done. But it was in a separate script. Thanks for the comment that eval will not complete until the command completes. Though this is confusing. If the parent process which has eval in its script finishes, then eval has to finish. I hope you understand my query. The comment box does not allow me to explain visually. Thanks again

Comment: If you replace the `open $0` with `open my $fh, '-|', 'sleep 10' || die;` you'll see what I mean by having to wait for a subprocess (the shell sleep).  But otherwise, no, a normal command should not block the alarm.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when porting a Linux Perl script to Windows.

I solved it by ...

Creating a non-blocking socket

```
$recsock = IO::Socket::INET->new(
                             LocalPort => 68,
                             Proto => "udp",
                             Broadcast => 1,
                            Blocking => 0,
                             ) or die "socket: $@";
```

Adding $continue variable to the timeout handle

```
# Timeout handle
$SIG{ALRM} = sub { 
    print "timeout\n";
    $continue = 1;
};
```

and checking for the $continue to become true when the timeout occurs:

```
    alarm($timeout);
     while(1){
         $recsock->recv($newmsg, 1024);
         eval {
            $packet = Net::Package->new($newmsg); 
             ...
        };
        sleep 0.1;
        last if ($continue);
    }
    alarm(0);
```