# Setting a timeout for DBD::Pg database connection

Tags: perl, postgresql, timeout, dbi

I have tried this in my Perl code, but the `timeout` doesn't work:

```
 my $dbh = DBI->connect($db, $db_user, $db_pass,{ timeout => 5 });
```

I want to set a timeout on the connection to a postgresql database: how can I do that ?

Comment: Is the `timeout` attribute documented anywhere, or did you just guess and hope that it would work?

Comment: i guess that, dont give any error, but dont work :(

Comment: Does setting the value through an environment variable achieve what you want? See my response below and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-envars.html - the postgreSQL client libraries (`libpq`) have several ways of adjusting configuration settings that might not always be exposed in the application language binding.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use alarm for that.

```
local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { print "timeout occurred\n" }; # NB: \n required 
alarm $timeout; # set your value here 
my $dbh = DBI->connect($db, $db_user, $db_pass);
alarm 0;
```

See more on:
http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html

Later Edit:

this seems to work, please see if it what you need:

```
use DBI;

my $timeOut = 5;
$SIG{ALRM} = \&timeout;
$SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE',
alarm($timeOut);

my $pid = fork();
if ($pid) { # Parent
   print "Started child process id: $pid\n";
} elsif ($pid == 0) { # Child
  my $dbh = DBI->connect($db, $db_user, $db_pass);
} else { # Unable to fork
   die "ERROR: Could not fork new process: $!\n\n";
}

waitpid ($pid, 0);
alarm(0);

sub timeout {
     print "timeout occured";
     kill 9, $pid;
}
```

Second edit:
The main problem you have with alarm can be if you are using Windows. 
See [Why doesn't die in alarm signal handler kill the process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204637/why-doesnt-die-in-alarm-signal-handler-kill-the-process)

Comment: in what way didn't work? didn't work is not good enough for debugging an issue :)

Comment: i set the timeout to 5 seconds, and did not timeout on 5 seconds :(

Comment: Let  me understand: you want to have a connection that exists for 5 seconds and after that you want to close that connection? Because I don't get "did not timeout". If the connection succeed you won't have a timeout. Can you, please be more explicit in what you want to achieve?

Comment: See my later edit, I've tried and seems to work, see if you can integrate this idea with what you need.

Comment: ++ though I think alarn() has issues on Windows platforms. Are you able to compare the effectiveness of the "in application" perl approach with the postgres client library configuration and environment settings way of doing this (as described in the second part of my post)?

Comment: @G.Cito: appears that alarm() has some problems on Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204637/why-doesnt-die-in-alarm-signal-handler-kill-the-process. In my opinion your answer is correct, the best way to ensure a timeout is from postgres config, the problem may arise when you are not the administrator of the database and you need the timeout "in application".

Comment: Good point. If you are a shipping an application you'd want that control. Setting `$ENV{ PGCONNECT_TIMEOUT }` might be the solution there but right now I'm unable to test whether is has the desired effect. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this using the constructor as far as I know.  However this can be done using PostgreSQL client configuration parameters - you can use configuration files or environment variables to change your connection settings.

Generally speaking, [`DBD::Pg`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Pg#connect) does allow for a lot of "transparent" timeout handling through the use of connection and query caching.  An example of this sort approach is the [Mojolicious](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious) and `DBD::Pg` based [`Mojo::Pg`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Pg) module.

### Setting `connect_timeout` in PostgreSQL Client Configuration

**NB:** You can also use an environment variable or the `service` parameter  (see the [`DBD::Pg` documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Pg#connect)) to refer your connection handle to the [`pg_service.conf` file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/libpq-pgservice.html) while calling your constructor. Using the `service` parameter or `$PGSERVICE` you can adjust timeout values in that configuration file. The `pg_service.conf` file is a system wide or user specific file which can set values for specific PostgreSQL "services".

You can set [`connect_timeout`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/libpq-connect.html) value for example. This latter approach should work for any client libraries linked against `libpq`.  I'm not certain how `DBD::Pg` uses the values set there or whether they can be made available to `DBI` applications. It's also not clear this is what you want.

You might try looking at any available code for existing `DBD::Pg` perl applications to see how other developers have dealt with timeouts and database connections.  Django, PHP and possibly other languages which use `libpq` to connect to PostgreSQL are able to use [`PGCONNECT_TIMEOUT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-envars.html) environment variable directly. Setting this in your shell or via `$ENV{PGCONNECT_TIMEOUT}` may work in your case as well.

---

### "Timeouts" in your application

If you want to control how your application attempts to reestablish a connections to the database when it becomes unavailable, or if you want to stop trying to connect (say at startup time) if the database server is not responding, then setting `{ RaiseError=>1 }` and using `eval` and `alarm` (see the [`DBI` "Timeout" documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Timeout)) to check for errors from within your application - as [@Heto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2886599/heto) suggests, is the standard approach - at least **on UNIX platforms**.

For simple startup timeout you could do something like:

```
use DBI;

sub dbh_connect { 
  my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Pg:dbname=test", '', '',); 
}

my $timeout = 5;
my $time    = time + $timeout;
while ( ! dbh_connect() ) { 
   say "connecting"; 
   sleep 1;
   if ( time >= $time ) { 
     die "unable to connect after $timeout seconds" ;  
   } 
}
```

and avoid delving into signals. While your application is running you can check on the connection *manually* with a minimal test query:

```
if ( ! $dbh->ping ) { print "Unable to connect to database\n" } ;
```

If you want to periodically check that your connection is up and working, then the [`$dbh->ping`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Pg#ping) and [`$dbh->pg_ping`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Pg#pg_ping) functions are both useful.